# Navbar blocked by image

Tags: html, css

I have a small website and when I'm on mobile view the image is blocking my navbar. Please help. [image]

```
    @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #696969;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .cheese {
        display: block;
    }
    .logo {
        margin-left: -8em;
    }
    .slidershow {
        width: 30em;
        height: 20em;
    }
}
```

Above is all of my CSS for when my slideshow page is moved to mobile view.

Below is my HTML. The HTML shows my navigation div which is for the sidebar when moved down to mobile view. Below that is my html for the slideshow.

```
        <div class="navigation">
        <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r4" class="bar"></label>
        <label for="r5" class="bar"></label>
    </div> 

    <div class="slidershow middle">
         
        <div class="slides">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">      
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4"> 
            <input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">
            <div class="slide s1">
                <img src="images/IMG_1129.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/image2.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/image3.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/image0 (1).jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/image1.jpeg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. W do not debug pictures. CSS alone is not enough to reproduce the issue. Your HTML markup matters and is required!

Comment: Do you want the image to resize or do you want it to be behind the nav?

Comment: Was just wanting it to be behind the nav, I'm relatively new to this so just not quite sure what to do. I could add my html if that's needed.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, just needed to work my HTML around. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my code recently, and although I probably didn't find the best answer, I found one that would make do. All I did was add a few break tags between the image/header box and navbar. Like so:

```
<header>
    <img src="images/Logo.jpg" alt="Roar Just Learn Logo" class="Logo">
</header>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#">Page 3</a>
    <a href="#">Page 4</a>
    <a href="bib.html">Bibliography</a>
</nav>
```